# Given an executable can I determine values of GOOS and GOARCH used to build it?

Tags: go

The title pretty much sums it up. How can I determine what the values of GOOS and GOARCH was given just the go executable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT:** The behavior of `runtime.GOROOT()` changed in Go 1.10, for details, see [Go 1.10 release notes # Runtime](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#runtime). Basically now `runtime.GOROOT()` checks if the `GOROOT` environment variable is set, and if so, its value is returned. If not, it returns the `GOROOT` value recorded at compile time.

---

Check out the [`runtime`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/) package:

> The GOARCH, GOOS, GOPATH, and GOROOT environment variables complete the set of Go environment variables. They influence the building of Go programs (see https://golang.org/cmd/go and https://golang.org/pkg/go/build). **GOARCH, GOOS, and GOROOT are recorded at compile time** and made available by constants or functions in this package, but they do not influence the execution of the run-time system.

A list of possible combinations for `GOARCH` and `GOOS` can be found here: https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment

So what you are looking for are constants in the `runtime` package:

```
runtime.GOOS
runtime.GOARCH
```

And they will exactly contain the values that were present when your app was built.

For example see this simple app:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOOS)
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOARCH)
}
```

Let's say `GOOS=windows` and `GOARCH=amd64`. Running it with `go run xx.go` will print:

```
windows
amd64
```

Build an exe from it (e.g. `go build`). Running the exe has the same output.

Now change `GOARCH` to `386`. If you run it with `go run` (or build an exe and run that), it will print:

```
windows
386
```

If you run the previously built exe, it will still print:

```
windows
amd64
```

Comment: In addtion to that, the [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) utility pretty reliably determines the arch and OS, both the GNU version and the BSD version.

Comment: Thanks Markus, file is what I was looking for initially and actually solves the problem the title asks about. But using runtime is a better option for my specific use case since I can re-compile the executable to tell me what it is.