# go executable somehow determines the wrong GOROOT

Tags: shell, go

There is a (non-Go) application that is running a Go executable as a server subprocess. That subprocess itself invokes the `go` command for certain operations.

Application -> Go server -> `go` executable

All of these are built on a system with Go 1.11.1 installed. And, on that system, there are no issues. However, on another machine it is failing in a way that I cannot understand. It turns out that system has Go 1.11.5 installed.

Here is the error produced by the Go server process, running on a machine with Go 1.11.5 installed:

```
"couldn\'t exec \'go [list -e -json -compiled -test=true -export=false -deps=true -find=false -- 
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/builtin]\': chdir 
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/builtin: no such file or directory *os.PathError"
```

I've determined that the string `/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec` is in fact embedded in the Go server executable. I used `strings` to do this.

GOROOT is not overridden on either machine.

On my machine, `go env GOROOT` reports:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec
```

On the target machine, `go env GOROOT` reports:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.5/libexec
```

As a test, I used the exact same environment setup to run `go env` in my host application instead of starting the server process. This also produces a GOROOT of `/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.5/libexec` on the target machine.

If I **do** override GOROOT to be `/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.5/libexec` in the environment that spawns my Go server process, things work correctly on the target machine.

So, I have a workaround of first capturing GOROOT with `go env`, and then overriding GOROOT in the server process's environment.

My understanding is you should never be setting GOROOT, yet it appears somehow the GOROOT settings mismatch is the issue. And I'm particularly stumped because `go env` looks exactly like I think it should on both machines in all cases I can think to test.

I still suspect this has something to do with the shell environment that is setup for running the server subprocesses.

Does anyone have an insight into what might be wrong?

Comment: [`runtime.GOROOT()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOROOT) does not return the value of the `GOROOT` environment variable, it returns the recorded value of `GOROOT` **from compile time**. See [Given an executable can I determine values of GOOS and GOARCH used to build it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669727/given-an-executable-can-i-determine-values-of-goos-and-goarch-used-to-build-it/35669816#35669816) So if the go app uses `runtime.GOROOT()`, you can't override that with environment variables.

Comment: Interesting thank you!

Comment: Actually, this changed in [Go 1.10](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#runtime). `runtime.GOROOT()` returns the `GOROOT` env var if set, and if not, it returns the `GOROOT` recorded at compile time.